# Disabling odoo 9 progress bar

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

How do i disable this progress bar on the top menu in Odoo 9.It apparently brings a wizard that shows you how to configure and use inventory.Thank you.

[progress-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6anCc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login as administrator (or any user who has access to the Settings)
Activate debug mode

Go to Settings -> Technical -> User Interface -> Planners

Find the inventory planner, click on deactivate.

Then refresh the page.

Navigate back to the Inventory menu and the `progressbar` on the top should be gone.